# Two Headsets in one Discord

Tags: windows, audio, discord

The situation is - I got two people sharing one room and only one PC that is running discord. Both should be able to talk and hear discord.

Is there any way in windows that will allow multiple microphones to be mixed to one input device that can be used in discord and the output from discord being delivered to both headsets as output too?

I’m aware on Mac you can achieve such a thing very easily with loopback and with a bit more hassle also by using the built-in audio-midi-setup but I’m drawing a blank for how to get this working in Windows.

Comment: Discord does not support multiple inputs in the way you describe

Comment: @Ramhound `Is there any software on windows that will allow multiple microphones to be mixed to one input device` with that quoted, it's off-topic here.

Comment: I agree, glazed over that sentence

Comment: @Ramhound I know Discord does only allow one input, I’ve got the same issue on my Mac too, but it’s quite easy to create a virtual audio device and then assign all Chanels of both inputs to it as well as doing the reverse for the output channels with both devices even being able to individually control volume. It’s even easier to do this with 3rd party software, but I can’t find a setting like this in windows.

Comment: @TomYan the windows mixer seems to be quite featureless in comparison, which is why I asked for a 3rd party software in the first place. But if you know any on-board solution that is even better, thanks in advance and let me know how to do it without, I’ve edited the question accordingly to ask for on-board solutions 
Thank you so much for your support and solution off this 